# First item in table looks misaligned

Tags: tables

I'm having some problems with tables in Latex, when I use:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|c c c c c|} 
 \hline
 Punto & Caudal & Altura & Potencia & Rendimiento \\ 
 \hline\hline\
 1 & 0 & 9 & 87 & 0\\ 
 \hline
 2 & 0,8 & 8,6 & 107,1 & 17,5\\
 \hline
 3 & 1,6 & 7,6 & 122,7 & 27 \\
 \hline
 4 & 2,4 & 6 & 135,3 & 29 \\
 \hline
 5 & 3,2 & 3 & 136 & 19,5 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Puntos de funcionamiento a 50Hz}
\end{table}
```

The first number in the table (1) will look misaligned with the rest of the column:
[image: Table]

Comment: Welcome! Remove the backslash at the end of `\hline\hline\ `, i.e. use only `\hline\hline`.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to fixing the obvious issue by deleting the stray `\` (backslash) character after `\hline\hline`, you may want to take a few more steps to improve the "look" of the table. Here are some suggestions:

- Use a `\centering` instruction instead of a `center` environment. Doing so will decrease the vertical gap between the `tabular` environment and the table caption.
- Align the numbers in the four data columns on their (explicit or implicit) decimal markers. This may be achieved by using the `S` column type provided by the [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) package.
- Give the table a much more open "look" by omitting all vertical lines and usinger fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines. I suggest you use `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) package instead of `\hline` and `\hline\hline`.

The following screenshot shows the effect of implementing these suggestions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}} % use comma as output decimal marker

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c c c c c|} 
   \hline
   Punto & Caudal & Altura & Potencia & Rendimiento \\ 
   \hline\hline % <-- no "\" at end of this line...
   1 & 0 & 9 & 87 & 0\\ 
   \hline
   2 & 0,8 & 8,6 & 107,1 & 17,5\\
   \hline
   3 & 1,6 & 7,6 & 122,7 & 27 \\
   \hline
   4 & 2,4 & 6 & 135,3 & 29 \\
   \hline
   5 & 3,2 & 3 & 136 & 19,5 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Initial version}

\bigskip\bigskip

\centering % <-- use "\centering", not "\begin{center}" and "\endcenter}"
\begin{tabular}{@{} c T{1.1} T{1.1} T{3.1} T{2.1} @{}} 
   \toprule
   Punto & {Caudal} & {Altura} & {Potencia} & {Rendimiento} \\ 
   \midrule
   1 & 0 & 9 & 87 & 0\\ 
   2 & 0,8 & 8,6 & 107,1 & 17,5\\
   3 & 1,6 & 7,6 & 122,7 & 27 \\
   4 & 2,4 & 6 & 135,3 & 29 \\
   5 & 3,2 & 3 & 136 & 19,5 \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Updated version}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advices! As you can see, I've just begun learning latex, but the community is making it easier for me to learn.